POST variables to adaptive card template
I have a simple adaptive card template that takes a variable and posts it to a Microsoft Teams Channel. However, when I'm sending my POST request I see a 202 code but nothing ends up in Teams. The template and data seem valid when using https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ I would expect a Teams message to arrive in my channel when sending the data in a POST request.
Template
{
"type": "AdaptiveCard",
"body": [
    {
        "type": "TextBlock",
        "text": "${description}",
        "wrap": true
    }
],
"$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
"version": "1.5"
}

Payload/Body
{"description": "Test message"}

Workflow

Error
The execution of template action 'Send_each_adaptive_card' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerOutputs()?['body']?['attachments']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.

What would be the correct way to use variables in the template or send variables through a POST request?

what is the full error message you get?

I've managed to find an error and updated it. So the payload is wrong that im sending.

okay, what is in the body.attachments from the webhook request?

It’s a simple error, you can’t loop over null, therefore, add a condition to check if it’s null before performing the for each.

The payloads in the question. I cant seem to find any docs on the correct way to format what im sending into teams. If I send description from the root, attachments, body nothing works as idk the format it wants the variables to be passed into the template. hence the post is asking what the correct way to send the POST request would be.

@mRyan, this has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756214/converting-teams-webhook-with-payload-type-messagecard-to-be-used-in-power-autom
