Converting Teams Webhook with payload type MessageCard to be used in Power Automate "Post to channel when a webhook request is received" workflow
Microsoft decided to deprecate Office 365 connectors. They announced the change on Jul. 3rd, 2024 and all existing connectors will stop working on Oct. 1st, 2024, a quick 3 month turnaround:
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams/
We use a Teams Webhook connector to send ticketing info into a Teams channel so our support team gets notifications of a new ticket. The payload from the ticketing system looks like this:
{  
   "@context": "https://schema.org/extensions",  
   "@type": "MessageCard",  
   "themeColor": "0072C6",  
   "title": "Title text....",  
   "text": "Body test...",  
   "potentialAction": []
}

We followed the process placed in Teams to convert our Webhook to a Power Automate workflow, and we receive the following error:

Action 'Send_each_adaptive_card' failed: The execution of template action 'Send_each_adaptive_card' failed: the result of the evaluation of 'foreach' expression '@triggerOutputs()?['body']?['attachments']' is of type 'Null'. The result must be a valid array.

This is because it expects the following format:
{
    "type": "message",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "version": "1.0",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "TextBlock",
                        "text": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}

This is an image of the workflow:
https://i.sstatic.net/6H1co2UB.png
When reviewing the workflow, it expects the following schema:
{
    "schema": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
            "type": {
                "type": "string"
            },
            "attachments": {
                "type": "array",
                "items": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "contentType": {
                            "type": "string"
                        },
                        "content": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                                "$schema": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "type": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "version": {
                                    "type": "string"
                                },
                                "body": {
                                    "type": "array",
                                    "items": {
                                        "type": "object",
                                        "properties": {
                                            "type": {
                                                "type": "string"
                                            }
                                        },
                                        "required": [
                                            "type"
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "required": [
                        "contentType",
                        "content"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

And then the "Send each adaptive card" node parses the object in the following way:
{
  "type": "Foreach",
  "foreach": "@triggerOutputs()?['body']?['attachments']",
  "actions": {
    "Post_your_own_adaptive_card_as_the_Flow_bot_to_a_channel": {
      "type": "OpenApiConnection",
      "inputs": {
        "parameters": {
          "poster": "Flow bot",
          "location": "Channel",
          "body/recipient/groupId": "bf7cf33f-40a6-4621-a8db-c942c38dbe75",
          "body/recipient/channelId": "19:ceb7fa98527f44d18372571c9a3e42dc@thread.tacv2",
          "body/messageBody": "@item()?['content']"
        },
        "host": {
          "apiId": "/providers/Microsoft.PowerApps/apis/shared_teams",
          "connection": "shared_teams",
          "operationId": "PostCardToConversation"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "runAfter": {}
}

So it is looking for the attachments array and iterating through.
I tried several changes to alter the "foreach" code and parse the MessageCard object, but none were successful. Is there a way to alter the schema or to change the foreach code to properly parse the MessageCard object?
The alternative is for us to take the MessageCard object that we are receiving from the API and convert it to the appropriate format as an object with an array of attachments. We would like to avoid doing this if possible, but it may be the best approach.
Update:
For those that are curious how to transform their payload from MessageCard to AdaptiveCard (which is what our team ended up doing to avoid trying to figure this out in the PowerAutomate workflow), our new payload looks like this now:
    {
        "type": "message",
        "attachments": [
            {
                "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
                "content": {
                    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
                    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                    "version": "1.0",
                    "msteams": {
                        "width": "Full"
                    },
                    "body": [
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": {Title},
                            "weight": "bolder",
                            "size": "medium",
                            "wrap": "true"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "TextBlock",
                            "text": {Body},
                            "wrap": "true"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }


You need to show us your workflow and a sample trigger. This should be easily fixed.

You can transform the MessageCard payload into the expected AdaptiveCard format before sending it to the Power Automate flow.

@Nivedipa-MSFT True, that was what I was suggesting in the alternative at the end of my post. We would like to avoid this if possible by editing the workflow instead to consume the MessageCard payload, but it may indeed be more simple to transform to AdaptiveCard.

@Skin I added an image of the Workflow to the post, but I also have all the code in there already so I am not sure what exactly you are looking for. Let me know and I can add it in. I am showing the MessageCard payload above and that is being sent into the Workflow.

The sample trigger is more what I was after.  Show an example of that if you can.  You've provided the schema but I want a failed trigger data sample.  It's pretty simple though, the value of the array is null, so it fails.

The idea where we tell our application layers to use the new AdaptiveCard format is applicable to only some use cases, but not others.  For instance, I have a Splunk application that sends alerts to a Microsoft Teams channel using the MessageCard format.  I don't have any control over what format Splunk sends those alerts.  Thus, I'd prefer a way to convert MessageCard to AdaptiveCard in the flow itself.

Microsoft has postponed the retirement through December 2025. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/retirement-of-office-365-connectors-within-microsoft-teams. You can ignore the worthless comments from so-called MSFTs asking irrelevant questions that have nothing to do with the problem.

@KevinRF This is good news, I know the timeline was going to be a huge issue for some teams that used connectors heavily. Thanks for this update!

Your "update" helped me.  I just copied and pasted that JSON while updating the body parameter, and it worked instantly.  Thanks!

@jhickok, glad to hear it was helpful to you!

I also posted this in the Microsoft support channel, and I received an answer there:
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/converting-teams-webhooks-to-power-automate/23704b44-aa49-4b5d-84a3-2c760d195f3e
The answer:
"
What you can do is add a compose step immediately after the webhook received trigger, and perform the transformation into what you want there, e.g.
https://i.sstatic.net/ywukRj0w.png
I got that working from the guidance here - https://github.com/prometheus/alertmanager/issues/3920#issuecomment-2219950227
"
I did not confirm this works, as I have already adapted my payload instead of editing the Workflow, but it seems to be a sound approach.

I couldn't find anything out of the box to convert MessageCards to Adaptative Cards. My solution was to replace Microsoft Teams webhooks with custom webhooks on all my apps and create a template using the template designer
Then I had to make several changes to the default PowerAutomate workflow

Add an extra step to parse the webhook JSON so I can pick the body sent from my application. This is what my application is sending on the webhook (built with designer):


{
    "type": "AdaptiveCard",
    "body": [
        {
            "type": "Image",
            "url": "${creator.profileImage}",
            "altText": "${creator.name}",
            "size": "Small"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "size": "Medium",
            "weight": "Bolder",
            "text": "{{.Title}}"
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "spacing": "None",
            "text": "Created {{DATE(${{.StartedAt}},SHORT)}}",
            "isSubtle": true,
            "wrap": true
        },
        {
            "type": "TextBlock",
            "text": "${description}",
            "wrap": true,
            "color": "Attention"
        },
        {
            "type": "FactSet",
            "facts": [
                {
                    "$data": "${properties}",
                    "title": "${key}:",
                    "value": "${value}"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "actions": [
        {
            "type": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "title": "Action.OpenUrl",
            "url": "${viewUrl}"
        }
    ],
    "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
    "version": "1.4"
}



I removed the 'for each' statement to post just one card with the parsed body as the Adaptative Card JSON, like this:
Post Card in channel configuration

This is how it looks:
PowerAutomate workflow
Hopefully, this will also work for you

This is useful information for some of my use cases, thank you.  Unfortunately, my Splunk application send the original MessageCard format to the webhook URLs, so I would prefer a solution that performed the MessageCard to AdaptiveCard conversion during the PowerAutomate flow.  Would you know of any resource explaining how to do this?

I agree, this doesn't specifically solve the issue of adapting the Workflow to consume the MessageCard payload instead of the AdaptiveCard, but it is still useful to see how you were able to workaround it, thanks Tomas!

Syntax Example for posting a webhook Event as AdaptiveCard in Microsoft Teams
I just got this working, for a similar issue. I was using deprecated azure 365 connectors to notify a Microsoft Teams channel when builds failed; Here's how to do the same via the Teams Workflow interface:

Get the Workflows App
Create a New flow, selecting to Create From Blank.
First add a Step called "When a Teams webhook request is received". Take note of the newly generated HTTP POST URL (the webhook), and provide it to Azure's Service Hooks page or wherever you want to be listening for events.
Add a Compose Step, setting the Inputs to something like the following


{
  "$schema": "http://adaptivecards.io/schemas/adaptive-card.json",
  "type": "AdaptiveCard",
  "version": "1.6",
  "body": [
    {
      "type": "Container",
      "items": [
        {
          "type": "TextBlock",
          "text": "@{triggerBody()?['sender']}",
          "weight": "Bolder",
          "wrap": true
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}



5. I suggest designing the desired look of your notification with the GUI here https://adaptivecards.io/designer/ then copy the json, replacing the field variables with the syntax example above.
6. Finally, create a  "Post Card in a chat or channel" step, outputs('Compose'). You will know the syntax is correct if it reformats it like you see in the example below

From there, you should be good to have messages automatically posting in your chosen teams channel with whatever data you feel is relevant!
P.S. if any of the incoming json is in an array, the syntax for passing it into the adaptive card is
@{triggerBody()?['nameOfArray'][0]['elementWithinArray']}


(A little SEO to help people find my solution) This is my solution to the Microsoft Teams warning that read as follows:
Action Required:
O365 connectors within Teams will be deprecated and notifications from this service will stop.
Learn more
about the timing and how the Workflows app provides a more flexible and secure experience. If you want to continue receiving these types of messages, you can use a workflow.
